# How can I reference two field without nid or uid?

Tags: views, entities

I have two content types: 1.- Equipment and 2.- Configuration

The First CT has the following fields:

- Title : is equipment id with autocomplete module serial and hide for not capture.
- model : Text
- Serial : Text

The Second CT has the following fields:

- Title : is conf id with autocomplete module serial and hide for not capture.
- installed os : Check box (Yes|No)
- App Installed : Check box (Yes|No)
- Network Access : Check box (Yes|No)
- Serial : Text

I need make a relationship with field serial and then create a view that shows all properties of CT two.

Regards Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

1. enable  entity reference module.
2. In the second CT , add an entity reference field.
3. In the field settings of the entity reference field select the first CT from a list of CT .
4. Create a view of second CT with all its related field.
5. Add relationship under the advanced options  ,  add an entity reference relationship referencing first CT.
6. Then add all the fields of first CT.
7. use the module link -
   https://drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters
   for equating the serial text field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I try make this with recommended step, but not work I no expert.